# 3rd Party Mac Developer Application: DEVELOPER NAME: no identity found

Tags: macos, app-store

I need to sign the code of an app I'm trying to submit to App Store through terminal:

```
codesign -f -s '3rd Party Mac Developer Application: DEVELOPER NAME' --entitlements "APPNAME.entitlements" "/AppPath/APPNAME.app"
```

but I'm getting the error `3rd Party Mac Developer Application: DEVELOPER NAME: no identity found` for all `DEVELOPER NAME` I try. I have no idea of what to fill in it.

What should I fill in order to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Keychain Access (command + space, write Keychain Access, hit enter).

Search for `3rd Party Mac Developer Application` in the search bar.,

---

**IF THERE ARE RESULTS:**

you should see a certificate, and if you click on it you will see `3rd Party Mac Developer Application: Your Name (ABCDEFGHIJ)`, so you want to replace `DEVELOPER NAME` in the terminal line with `Your Name (ABCDEFGHIJ)` and proceed with you work.

---

**IF THERE AREN'T RESULTS:**

1. go to https://developer.apple.com/account/,
2. press Certificates, Ids & Profiles,
3. change from iOS, tvOS, watchOS to macOS
4. create new certificate at Certificates, in the `+` button in the top right corner
5. choose Production > Mac App Store and hit continue
6. choose Mac App Distribution and hit continue

The rest is straightforward, it will ask you to create CSR file but it tells you how to. After you've done all of this, you will be able to download the new certificate, and after you download, open the file and install it the way it comes. 3rd Party Mac Developer Application certificate is now in Keychain Access. Now follow the ***if there are results*** steps.

---

Hope that helps.